# Getting Hbase Exception No regions passed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

Hi i am new to Hbase and im trying to learn how to load bulk data to Hbase table using MapReduce

But i am getting below Exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No regions passed
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2.writePartitions(HFileOutputFormat2.java:307)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2.configurePartitioner(HFileOutputFormat2.java:527)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(HFileOutputFormat2.java:391)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(HFileOutputFormat2.java:356)
>           at JobDriver.run(JobDriver.java:108)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
>           at JobDriver.main(JobDriver.java:34)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

This is mY Mapper Code

```html
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  
  
  System.out.println("Value in Mapper"+value.toString());
  String[] values = value.toString().split(",");
         byte[] row = Bytes.toBytes(values[0]);
         ImmutableBytesWritable k = new ImmutableBytesWritable(row);
         KeyValue kvProtocol = new KeyValue(row, "PROTOCOLID".getBytes(), "PROTOCOLID".getBytes(), values[1]
                         .getBytes());
         context.write(k, kvProtocol);
}
```

This is my Job Configuration

```html
public class JobDriver extends Configured implements Tool{

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  ToolRunner.run(new JobDriver(), args);
  System.exit(0);

 }

 @Override
 public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  // HBase Configuration
  System.out.println("**********Starting Hbase*************");
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
                Job job = new Job(conf, "TestHFileToHBase");
                job.setJarByClass(JobDriver.class);
                job.setOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
                job.setOutputValueClass(KeyValue.class);
                job.setMapperClass(LoadMapper.class);
                job.setOutputFormatClass(HFileOutputFormat2.class);                
                HTable table = new HTable(conf, "kiran");
                FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://192.168.61.62:9001/sampledata.csv"));
                FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://192.168.61.62:9001/deletions_6.csv"));
                HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(job, table);
                //System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
 }
}
```

Can Anyone please help me in resolvin the exception.

Comment: Can you please share the complete code of your Mapper? Do you have a Reducer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create the table first. You can do it with the below code

```
//Create table and do pre-split
HTableDescriptor descriptor = new HTableDescriptor(
Bytes.toBytes(tableName)
);

descriptor.addFamily(
new HColumnDescriptor(Constants.COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME)
);

HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(config);

byte[] startKey = new byte[16];
Arrays.fill(startKey, (byte) 0);

byte[] endKey = new byte[16];
Arrays.fill(endKey, (byte)255);

admin.createTable(descriptor, startKey, endKey, REGIONS_COUNT);
admin.close();
```

or directly from the hbase shell with the command:

```
create 'kiran', 'colfam1'
```

The exception is caused because the startkeys list is empty: [line 306](http://search-hadoop.com/c/HBase:hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/HFileOutputFormat2.java%7C%7CincrementColumnValue)

More info can be found [here](http://blog.thumbtack.net/hbase-big-data-arrays-loading-via-bulk-load/).

Note that the table name must be the same with the one you use in your code (kiran).